# Disable auto scroll form right to left after click header to sort the rows in PySide6

Tags: qt, pyside6

I use QFileSystemMode, QSortFilterProxyModel and QTreeView to create a file manager in PySide6. I face a problem:
[image]

When I click the header vessel, it sort the files and auto scroll to left edge like:
[image]

I try some codes like below but it doesn't work:

```
    self.tree_view.setAutoScroll(False)
```

Can anyone give me some tips? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: I change the treeview to tableview and it can works! Thanks anyway.